# Isotope masonry - displays content wrong

Tags: css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have an issue with masonry layout - I can't fit 64% and 32% columns in one row correctly..

Jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/h6ammhbo/

This is my masonry code:

```
var $container = $('#masonry-container').imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.item_article',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            masonry: {
                gutter: 5
            }
        });
    });
```

and the layout:

[image: failed layout]

my css:
for the big item: `.article_60{ width: 64% }`
for small items: `.article_30{ width: 32% }`

but I can't get layout I need, also there is no spaces between items, what is the problem here?

Comment: fitRows does not have any options. It is not used with masonry as you have it set up. Since you are using fitRows, it will not slide up since it is doing exactly as it is supposed to since you have two different height items above the ones you want to slide up. Click fitRows [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) and watch what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try different [layout modes](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html). For example `packery`. Have in mind that some layout modes has to be downloaded separately and not included in main source file.

Comment: also we should always remember that boxes needs to be a multiple in size. Like w1: 30%  - w2: 15% otherwise you will eventually end up with empty gaps even tho you use packery layoutmode

Answer (score 0):

You can choose layout mode like this http://prntscr.com/6eyn4n http://prntscr.com/6eyn92

Answer (score 0):

Items needs to be multiple in theirs respective sizes:
if one item is 400 another needs to be 200 and so on..